# How to show parent midlet from another java program in j2me

Tags: java-me, midp

I am developing a j2me application where there is one parent midlet which calls other java programs. Parent midlet is of implicit list which contains 4 elements. On clicking any of the elements an appropriate java program is called. Everything is working fine, but i don't understand how to show parent midlet from java program on clicking of back button.

Please provide examples.
this is my parent midlet code

```
package hello;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Contacts extends MIDlet implements CommandListener,Runnable {
Display display=null;

private Form form=new Form("Contacts");
private List menu=new List("Contact Menu",Choice.IMPLICIT);
private Command exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 2);
private Command ok=new Command("Ok",Command.SCREEN,1);
private Command back = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 1);

private Alert alert;
public Contacts()
{
    display = Display.getDisplay(this);
  try{
      menu.append("Add Contact", Image.createImage("/contact_new.png"));
      menu.append("Delete Contact",Image.createImage("/delete-icon.png"));
      menu.append("Get Contact",Image.createImage("/document-edit.png"));
      menu.append("View Contacts",Image.createImage("/view.png"));
      menu.addCommand(ok);
      menu.addCommand(exit);
      menu.setCommandListener(this);

      }
     catch(IOException ie)
     {
             }
        }
    public void startApp() {
    display.setCurrent(menu);
        }

    public void pauseApp() {
        }

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
      }
public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable displayable) {
if (command == exit) {
  destroyApp(true);
  notifyDestroyed();
  return;
  } 
     switch (menu.getSelectedIndex ()) {
    case 0:
         new ac (this);//call to java program
               break;

    case 1:
         new dc (this);
        break;
    case 2:
        new gc(this);
        break;
   case 3:
         new vc(this);
           break;

    default:
        System.err.println ("Unexpected choice...");

        break;

    }


  }


        }
```

Comment: Are the other java program , that the parent MIDlet calls , a j2me program or a j2se program ?

Comment: the other java programs are j2me programs.

Comment: other java programs are j2me programs.They do not extend Midlet.Only parent midlet extends Midlet.

Comment: please show code that you use in "parent midlet" / "implicit list"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any API in standard J2ME to interact between MIDlets. At least that is already released. There is some Nokia private API to do some such kind of operations.